# function not working tho props have been passed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, use-state

Both of my completeTodo and removeTodo function is not working tho i have passed the props to the Todo function and in the ***Todo*** component rendered in the App.js. Anyone knows what is wrong with my two function or anything, please help me! Thank you so much!

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Todo({ todo, index, completeTodo, removeTodo }) {
  console.log("hiiii");
  return (
    <div>
      <div className={todo.isCompleted ? "line-through" : ""}>
        <p>{todo.text}</p>
      </div>
      <button onCllick={() => completeTodo(index)}>completed</button>
      <button onCllick={() => removeTodo(index)}>X</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function TodoForm({ addTodo }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!value) return;
    addTodo(value);
    setValue("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="add new todo"
          value={value}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setValue(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
    {
      text: "eat lunch",
      isCompleted: false
    },
    {
      text: "do homework",
      isCompleted: false
    },
    {
      text: "go to school",
      isCompleted: false
    }
  ]);

  const addTodo = (text) => {
    const newTodos = [...todos, { text }];
    setTodos(newTodos);
  };

  const completeTodo = (index) => {
    console.log("completed");
    const newTodos = [...todos];
    newTodos[index].isCompleted = true;
    setTodos(newTodos);
  };

  const removeTodo = (index) => {
    console.log("deleted");
    const newTodos = [...todos];
    newTodos.splice(index, 1);
    setTodos(newTodos);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {todos.map((todo, index) => {
          return (
            <Todo
              key={index}
              index={index}
              todo={todo}
              completeTodo={completeTodo}
              removeTodo={removeTodo}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <div>
        <TodoForm addTodo={addTodo} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Sanbox link:https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-bash-ef4hk?file=/src/App.js:0-1979

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mutating the state.

```
const completeTodo = (index) => {
  console.log("completed");
  const newTodos = [...todos];
  newTodos[index].isCompleted = true; // <-- mutates todo object
  setTodos(newTodos);
};

const removeTodo = (index) => {
  console.log("deleted");
  const newTodos = [...todos];
  newTodos.splice(index, 1); // <-- mutates todo object
  setTodos(newTodos);
};
```

Along with shallow copying the array you need to also shallow copy any nested state that you are updating. The todo objects should also be new object references.

```
const completeTodo = (index) => {
  console.log("completed");
  setTodos((todos) =>
    // array.map to return new array
    todos.map((todo, i) =>
      i === index
        ? {
            ...todo, // shallow copy old todo object
            isCompleted: true
          }
        : todo
    )
  );
};

const removeTodo = (index) => {
  console.log("deleted");
  // array.filter to return new array
  setTodos((todos) => todos.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
};
```

Fix the buttons in the `Todo`, they aren't using the correct event handler.

```
<button onCllick={() => completeTodo(index)}>completed</button>
<button onCllick={() => removeTodo(index)}>X</button>
```

should be

```
<button onClick={() => completeTodo(index)}>completed</button>
<button onClick={() => removeTodo(index)}>X</button>
```

[image: Edit function-not-working-tho-props-have-been-passed]

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me! Btw, sorry for bothering you but i just have a little bit more to finish this project and i can't figure out the way to fix it, the thing is my increment and removeItem function is not working, if you don't mind i hope you can see it! Link:https://codesandbox.io/s/cart-code-addict-forked-rvtet. Thank you!

Comment: @naha Fixed increment/decrement quantity, removeItem, cleatCart, computing derived cart totals/tax: https://codesandbox.io/s/cart-code-addict-forked-8niws?file=/src/App.js